# How can I remove quotes from String on Swift?

Tags: swift, swift2

I am trying to remove quotes from Swift `String` something like:

"Hello"

so that the Swift `String` is just:

Hello

Comment: Are you 100% sure that the string actually contains quotation marks? Perhaps it is just how the Debugger or Playground *displays* the string?

Comment: @MartinR, was interesting to realise that quotes showing in Debugger is actual string variable containing quotes and has to be removed for my network api call to works. Once removed Debugger not showing quotes in printed variable anymore.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can simply use

**Swift 1**

```
var str: String = "\"Hello\""

print(str) // "Hello"

print(str.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\"", withString: "")) // Hello
```

**Update for Swift 3 & 4**

```
print(str.replacingOccurrences(of: "\"", with: "")) // Hello
```

Answer (score 14):

```
"\"Hello\"".stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: "\""))
```

Comment: This removes only quotation marks at the edges and leaves those in the middle. Depending on the OP's intention this could be just as correct.

Answer (score 3):

In Swift 3:

```
let myString = "\"Hello\""
print(myString)  // "Hello"

let myNewString = myString.replacingOccurrences(of: "\"", with: "")
print(myNewString) // Hello
```

Answer (score 2):

```
str.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\"", withString: "")
```

Answer (score 1):

//try like this

```
var strString = "\"Hello\""

strString = strString.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\"", withString: "")
```

Comment: not working now also am getting quotes in result string.

Answer (score 0):

you can use \ to remove Quotes from string

> \" (double quote)
>
> \' (single quote)

example:

```
NSString *s = @"your String";
NSCharacterSet *newStr = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"/""];
s = [[s componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet: newStr] componentsJoinedByString: @""];
NSLog(@"%@", s);
```

Comment: let myString = "Hello"
  let resulttext = myString.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\"", withString: "", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil)not working now also am getting quotes in result string

Comment: try: println("\(Hello!)"

Comment: any other way to remove quotes from string ?

Comment: You do realise that the console will print the quotes as a "decoration" to let you know that this is a string? Also `let string = "Hello"` creates a string with only `Hello` in it, as quotes in this statement simply tell the compiler - "This is a string".

Comment: now its working print(resultText) .thank you very much