# Unable to replace string in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xml, double-quotes, single-quotes

Trying to escape few special characters of string for sending it via xml api.

Tried below code but not working for all the occurrences of Single Quote (') and Double Quote (")

```
var strToReturn = "“Hello” ‘world’"
strToReturn = strToReturn.replacingOccurrences(of: "&", with: "&amp;")
strToReturn = strToReturn.replacingOccurrences(of: "<", with: "&lt;")
strToReturn = strToReturn.replacingOccurrences(of: ">", with: "&gt;")
strToReturn = strToReturn.replacingOccurrences(of: "‘", with: "&apos;")
strToReturn = strToReturn.replacingOccurrences(of: "“", with: "&quot;") 

print("Replaced string : \(strToReturn)")
```

Result is `&quot;Hello” &apos;world’`

If anyone can help, thanks!

Comment: what is the expected result?

Comment: &quot;Hello&quot; &apos;world&apos;

Comment: For anyone wondering how the _Single_ and _Double quotes_ inside the strings are generated --- Hold down **alt/option** and press **Square / Curly bracket** keys

Comment: `“ != ”` and `‘ != ’`

Comment: have a look for Quotation marks replace --- https://stackoverflow.com/a/37385081/4970453

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to specify replacement strings for `’` and `”` because `’ != ‘` and `” != “`

```
var strToReturn = "“Hello” ‘world’"
strToReturn = strToReturn.replacingOccurrences(of: "&", with: "&amp;")
strToReturn = strToReturn.replacingOccurrences(of: "<", with: "&lt;")
strToReturn = strToReturn.replacingOccurrences(of: ">", with: "&gt;")
strToReturn = strToReturn.replacingOccurrences(of: "‘", with: "&apos;")
strToReturn = strToReturn.replacingOccurrences(of: "“", with: "&quot;")
strToReturn = strToReturn.replacingOccurrences(of: "’", with: "&apos;")
strToReturn = strToReturn.replacingOccurrences(of: "”", with: "&quot;")
```

Comment: Silly mistake.. My bad. Noted, thanks for the help. It worked !!

Comment: Still mistake, self.replacingOccurrences(of: "‘", with: "'") fixed the issue

Answer (score 2):

The reason for this is because `”` is different than `“` and `’` is different than `‘`. So you need to add these lines too.

```
strToReturn = strToReturn.replacingOccurrences(of: "’", with: "&apos;")
strToReturn = strToReturn.replacingOccurrences(of: "”", with: "&quot;")
```

This will give you the expected result

Answer (score 2):

If you print the ascii values of the string you will see the quotes are not the same unicode character. So make sure you use the same unicode character or handle both case

```
strToReturn.characters.map{print($0, "\(String($0.unicodeScalars.first!.value, radix: 16, uppercase: true))")}

“ 201C
H 48
e 65
l 6C
l 6C
o 6F
” 201D
  20
‘ 2018
w 77
o 6F
r 72
l 6C
d 64
’ 2019
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working perfectly fine with me . I just changed the `strings` as I mentioned in the comments :

> For anyone wondering how the Single and Double quotes inside the strings are generated --- Hold down alt/option and press Square / Curly bracket keys

Just change the letters using the key combination and it will work

[image]

Answer (score 0):

the below extension is very useful

```
 var toReplaceSmartQuotes: String {
        return self.replacingOccurrences(of: "‘", with: "'").replacingOccurrences(of: "’", with: "'")
            .replaceCharacters(characters: "”", toSeparator: #"""#)
    }
    
    func replaceCharacters(characters: String, toSeparator: String) -> String {
        let characterSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: characters)
        let components = components(separatedBy: characterSet)
        let result = components.joined(separator: toSeparator)
        return result
    }
```

Comment: It say : Use of local variable 'components' before its declaration